# DBUnit & Postgres UUID Primary Key

Tags: postgresql, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I am trying to use DBUnit to run integration tests, however I am finding myself unable to insert the primary key columns, which obviously will not work with foreign keys referencing the primary key later on in the file.

For example, I have the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE attributes(
    attribute_id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    attribute VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(attribute_id)
);
```

And the DBUnit setup XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataset>
    <attributes attribute_id="233bc966-4fcd-4b46-88e6-3e07090f322d" attribute="Empathy" description="Empathy Description" />
</dataset>
```

When I attempt to run the test, I get the failure:

```
    org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: attributes.ATTRIBUTE_ID -  (Non-uppercase input column: attribute_id) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the
ap's column names are NOT case sensitive.
```

Here is the test being run:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@DbUnitConfiguration(dataSetLoader = TestConfiguration.FlatXmlDataLoaderProxy.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfiguration.class, TestConfiguration.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
public class ApplicationAssessmentJobTest {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationAssessmentJob applicationAssessmentJob;

    @Test
    @DatabaseSetup("/dbunit/ApplicationAssessmentJobTestSetup.xml")
    @DatabaseTearDown("dbunit/ApplicationAssessmentJobTestTearDown.xml")
    public void testJob() {
        ApplicationAssessmentJobModel model = new ApplicationAssessmentJobModel();
        model.setApplicationId(UUID.fromString("41fa1d51-c1ee-482b-80a7-a6eefda64436"));

        applicationAssessmentJob.receiveMessage(model);
    }
}
```

This error shown does not appear to be directly related to the underlying issue. If I remove the `attribute_id` column from the XML, the record is inserted.

Comment: Maybe I'm too late, but DbUnit won't recognize any vendor-specific data-types (such as `uuid`), unless you explicitly [use the vendor-specific data-type factory](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#typefactory). In your case, you should use an instance of `org.dbunit.ext.postgresql.PostgresqlDataTypeFactory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fighting with DBUnit/Spring-Test-DBUnit for most of my day, I decided to scrap that library and roll my own for the mere fact that DBUnit seems to be nothing but pain.

I was able to write a setup/teardown in about 40 SLoC in less than 30 minutes. It uses plain SQL, which is philosophically more in line with my choice of [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) over Hibernate. Certainly less than ideal, but 15 minutes of searching didn't turn up anything to handle a simple use case of running SQL on setup and on teardown. Worth noting is a requirement on a `java.sql.DataSource` Bean available from the `ApplicationContext`.

*DbInitTestExecutionListener.java*

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class DbInitTestExecutionListener implements TestExecutionListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {}

    @Override
    public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        DatabaseSetup setup = testContext.getTestMethod().getAnnotation(DatabaseSetup.class);

        if (setup != null) {
            if (setup.clearInsert()) {
                afterTestMethod(testContext);
            }

            ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();

            Arrays.asList(setup.value()).stream()
                    .map(ClassPathResource::new)
                    .forEach(populator::addScript);

            populator.execute(testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(DataSource.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        DatabaseTearDown tearDown = testContext.getTestMethod().getAnnotation(DatabaseTearDown.class);

        if (tearDown != null) {
            ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();

            Arrays.asList(tearDown.value()).stream()
                    .map(ClassPathResource::new)
                    .forEach(populator::addScript);

            populator.execute(testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(DataSource.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {}
}
```

*DatabaseTearDown.java*

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface DatabaseTearDown {
    String[] value();
}
```

*DatabaseSetup.java*

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface DatabaseSetup {
    boolean clearInsert() default true;

    String[] value();
}
```

With a minimal test configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfiguration.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbInitTestExecutionListener.class
})
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    @DatabaseSetup("/dbinit/TestSetup.sql")
    @DatabaseTearDown("/dbinit/TestTearDown.sql")
    public void testJob() {
      // TODO: Add test code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem and i finally found a solution.
As mentionned in the documentation, you need to override the default dbunit DatabaseConfig to set the IDataTypeFactory specific for PostgreSQL.

Here's my test configuration :

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public DatabaseConfigBean databaseConfigBean() {
    DatabaseConfigBean databaseConfigBean = new DatabaseConfigBean();
    databaseConfigBean.setDatatypeFactory(new PostgresqlDataTypeFactory());
    return databaseConfigBean;
}

@Bean(name = "dbUnitDatabaseConnection")
public DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean dbUnitDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException, DatabaseUnitException, IOException {
    DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean databaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean = new DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean();
    databaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean.setDatabaseConfig(databaseConfigBean());
    databaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean.setSchema("public");
    return databaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean;
}
```

Then, you need to specifiy that you will use custom IDatabaseConnection in your tests. Those connections will be create by the bean 'dbUnitDatabaseConnection'. For example, here's how I declare my spring test configuration :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringRepositoryConfigurationTest.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection = {"dbUnitDatabaseConnection"})
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message

```
org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: attributes.ATTRIBUTE_ID ...
```

suggests that dbunit is looking for a column named `ATTRIBUTE_ID`. Your CREATE TABLE statement creates a column named `attribute_id`.

If dbunit uses delimited identifiers, PostgreSQL will consider `"ATTRIBUTE_ID"` and `"attribute_id"` as two different identifiers. (In your case, two different columns.) If dbunit *doesn't* use delimited identifiers, PostgreSQL will fold to lower case, and it will consider `ATTRIBUTE_ID` and `attribute_id` to be the same identifier--`attribute_id`.

SQL standards require folding ordinary identifiers to upper case. PostgreSQL's behavior here is not standard, but it's not likely to change.

It *looks* like dbunit might be folding to upper case (following SQL standards) on its own. If that's the case, you can probably configure dbunit to use case-sensitive identifiers. (I don't know how to do that off the top of my head.)

Comment: That was my thought as well, but configuring the `FlatXmlDataSetLoader` to be case-sensitive did nothing to solve this problem. Of note, is that when one removes the `attribute_id` column, all other columns are inserted without problem. Further testing seems to indicate this issue has to do with the type of column and the default. Unfortunately I simply lack the time to discover the root cause.